# List of system preferences on OS X modifiable via CFPreferences?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, cfpreferences

I recently learned a way to read/modify a system preference using CFPreferences.

I used `CFPreferencesCopyValue` and `CFPreferencesSetValue` to read and modify a key `AppleInterfaceStyle`. This is used to control the Dark Mode in Yosemite.

I would like a way to also control the 'invert colour' and 'grayscale' property.

[image]

Is there a way to get a list of these system keys? I did not find any reference in the documentation.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to boot into Yosemite and look, but this setting will surely be hiding in either the "`com.apple.Accessibility.plist`" or maybe the "`com.apple.display.plist`" file.  Type in "`defaults read com.apple.Accessibility.plist`" in Terminal and let me know if you see something obvious in there.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I get the 'Domain xxx does not exist for `com.apple.display.plist` and `com.apple.Accessibility.plist`. However something like `com.apple.systemPreferences.plist` does work.